# How to pivot values into two columns using a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to get two new columns (stock type in this case) and their respective quantities.  I have tried to use PIVOT but it seems rather limited in SQL.

Tried to use PIVOT

This is part of a larger query but this is the piece I would like to have return as two columns - one for stock type 'A' and one for ' ' - blank.  As it is now this returns two rows - one for each stock type.

```
SELECT MATERIAL,
    CASE
        WHEN STOCK_TYPE = 'A'
        THEN 'UNCOVERED QTY'
        ELSE 'BLANK QTY'
    END AS [STOCK TYPE], 
    SUM(QUANTITY) AS 'QUANITTY' 

FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION 

WHERE STOCK_TYPE IN ('A','')

AND MATERIAL = '011040'

GROUP BY STOCK_TYPE,
         MATERIAL
```

This returns:

```
MATERIAL           STOCK TYPE    QUANITTY
------------------ ------------- ---------------------------------------
011040             BLANK QTY     67
011040             UNCOVERED QTY 1301

(2 rows affected)
```

I would like to return one row for the material with two columns - one for 'Uncovered Quantity' and one for ' Blank Quantity'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MATERIAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STOCK_TYPE = 'A' THEN QUANTITY END) as uncovered_qty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STOCK_TYPE <> 'A' THEN QUANTITY END) as blank_qty
FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION 
WHERE STOCK_TYPE IN ('A', '') AND MATERIAL = '011040'
GROUP BY MATERIAL;
```